# Internet doesn't work in VMWare workstation machine

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware-workstation

I just created a Windows 7 virtual machine in VMWare workstation 12 pro.
The internet shows that it is working but when opening internet explorer, it doesn't work, "Internet explorer cannot display the webpage".

This is my control panel showing that its supposed to work: 
[image: Screenshot of the network and sharing center in the guest]

These are my virtual network editor settings:
[image: VMware network settings]

As you may realize I am not very good at all this so some explained help would be very appreciated, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Could you show us your network settings from inside the guest? E.g. `ipconfig /all'.

Comment: I'm inclined to believe it is an DNS issue or possibly a poisioning of the browser proxy configuration. The MS Internet map actually downloads a text file, so unless the result being displayed is stale, the actual connectivity is working, leading me to believe that its either DNS or browser specific.

Answer (score -1):

Okay I found an answer if anyone has the same problem. Turn all security options in internet explorer to low and reset the default advanced settings on internet explorer. This fixed it for me!

Comment: without more context that sounds like an absolutely horrible idea.

Comment: okay I found the answer by myself and I could have just left my question like this but I felt like maybe I could help someone but posting the solution that I found. The response i get is 2 downvotes and someone saying that my solution is a horrible idea. Great community, thanks.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but you asked a question no one can answer (in that your solution has absolutely nothing to do with the facts you presented). Additionally there is significant danger to anyone who follows your advice, as it compromises  the security of the users browser. it would be irresponsible of the community to let your assertion stand without comment. After looking at everything, you probably had a proxy server configured (likely set by malware) and your reset of the browser cleared that configuration. This jives with every aspect of the problem and your fix.

Comment: @2000mroliver - A good answer has to be detailed enough that it can be other people with similar issues.  A vote on an answer can mean multiple things.  The answer must be helpful to the community, so an answer which presents a bad solution to a common problem, which itself generates a security problem is likely to recieve down votes.  A great way to recieve upvotes is to present a better solution to the problem, one that does not generate a security concern, one that directly solves your problem though.

Comment: Your question can be solved correctly, correctly just being securely, if you answered the outstanding questions in the comment section the community could answer your question.

Comment: alright im very sorry, I should have stayed silent. lol

Comment: not at all. communication is important. We don't want you to take your ball and go home. Any given community has norms, mores, and taboos, that take time and experience to learn. Even then someone will always rub you the wrong way on occasion. We are not looking for contrition; we're just trying to point you the right direction.  SuperUser is generally more friendly than, for instance, StackOverflow or Physics.stackexchange.org, or even ServerFault.org (where a server is hardware that costs 50k or else you are offtopic). They all have their own idiosyncrasies.